# My masculinity is of the interest of women and my sexuality of men

Tags: sentence-construction

> *My masculinity is of the interest of women and my sexuality of men*

What I'm trying to say is that; as a girl, my masculinity is something that women find interesting and that, in contrast, my sexuality is something that men find also interesting. But I'm trying to find a way to write that in a much shorter sentence, like what I have written in the quote box above. But I doubt that sounds right or that it's even grammatically correct. Can someone please help me to get it right?

Comment: If you are a girl, what sense does *my masculinity* make? It is not so clear.

Comment: @Shadowfax a girl can have as much masculinity as a guy can have femininity, I would say. Or are you saying that's not grammatically correct? I see all the time guys being feminine, can't a girl be masculine?

Comment: As J.R. put it, without additional context this might confuse a reader. I am one of those readers :)

Comment: @Shadowfax you did know I was talking about a girl: 
"If you are a girl, what sense does my masculinity make?". Most likely because I did mention it in the question: "What I'm trying to say is that; as a girl, ..." J.R is referring to the actual text where the sentence will be going. so, one, you're not one of the readers J.R. is referring to and second, that also means that it is your comments what's lacking sense.

Comment: When I said *I am one of those readers*, I referred only to the text in blockquote because that *is* the sentence we are talking about, and the explanation that follows is *in no way part* of the context. BTW, from those 2 ups in your question, one of them is from me, so chill!

Comment: @Shadowfax Again, you said: "**If you are a girl**, what sense does my masculinity make?". And I'd disagree with: "the explanation that follows is **in no way** part of the context". You actually seem to be contradicting yourself with some of your statements. Maybe you can expand a bit further so that what you're saying could make sense? The only thing clear ATM, I think, is that you agree with J.R..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *My masculinity is of the interest of women*...

From an English perspective, there are two problems that jump out at me. When talking about something interesting:

- we typically say *of interest* (not "of the interest"),
- we typically end with the preposition *to*, not *of*.

Therefore, the first part of your statement should probably be written as follows:

> *My masculinity is of interest to women*...

Moreover, we could make this even more concise by saying:

> *My masculinity interests women*...

---

As for the second part of your statement, I'd suggest using **parallelism**. As [one website](http://literarydevices.net/parallelism/) explains:

> Parallelism is the use of components in a sentence that are grammatically the same; or similar in their construction, sound, meaning or meter. Parallelism examples are found in literary works as well as in ordinary conversations.

When using this literary device, conjunctions are often omitted. So, you could say:

> *My masculinity interests women, my sexuality interests men*.

Another way to convey the same sentiment would be:

> *Women are interested in my masculinity; men are interested in my sexuality.*

---

Because masculinity is a trait often associated with men, those sentences might confuse a reader without any additional context. (If the readers already know you are writing as a woman, this would not be a problem.) If the sentence is to be read stand-alone, you could clarify it by saying something along the lines of:

> *As a woman with some masculine tendencies, my masculinity interests women, but my sexuality interests men*.

Comment: I liked the last part. +1 for that.